# Count number of columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, metadata

Is there a way to know the number of columns in SQL, something like count()...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [To get total number of columns in a table in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464991/to-get-total-number-of-columns-in-a-table-in-sql)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

one way

```
select count(*) from sys.columns
```

another

```
select count(*) from information_schema.columns
```

The bottom one does not have the system tables

**by table**

```
select count(*),table_name from information_schema.COLUMNS
GROUP BY table_name
```

**tables only**

```
select count(*),c.table_name 
from information_schema.COLUMNS c
JOIN information_schema.tables t ON c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
AND c.TABLE_Schema = t.TABLE_Schema
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'base table'  
GROUP BY c.table_name
```

**views only**

```
select count(*),c.table_name 
from information_schema.COLUMNS c
JOIN information_schema.tables t ON c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
AND c.TABLE_Schema = t.TABLE_Schema
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'view'  
GROUP BY c.table_name
```

Comment: Added the count grouped by table also

Answer (score 9):

```
Select Count(*) From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS Where TABLE_NAME='YourTableName'
```

or if you need to specify the schema

```
    Select Count(*) From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS Where TABLE_NAME='YourTableName' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YourSchema'
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work across multiple RDBMS's:

```
select count(*) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

And if you want to get fancy:

```
select TABLE_NAME,
       count(*)
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
group by TABLE_NAME
order by TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

For a particular table:

```
select * from sys.tables
where name = 'mytable';
```

Get the object_id from this, then use:

```
select count(*) from sys.columns
where object_id = 831342026;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Database_Name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name = 'Table_Name'
```

to Run 2 steps are needed : 
1- choose the database_Name to your database name 
2- Change Your Table Name 
Notes: if you didn't write database_Name like

```
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

retrieves System database only