# Finding number of columns returned by a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get the number of columns returned by an SQL query using SQL Server?

For example, if I have a query like following:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    A1, A2
```

It should return the total number of columns in table A1 + total number of columns in table A2. But the query might be more complicated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want the total number of columns?   Also, you should use proper join syntax, rather than implicit joins in the where clause.

Comment: There is some legacy code that I have to work with and I need to check at another place how many columns is returned. It is more like a debugging issue

Comment: I dont need the record count, I just need the total number of columns returned

Comment: why can't do you do this in whatever code you're executing the query from...if its in C# for instance you can get the number of returned columns and names fairly easily.

Comment: Best practice is to list off the columns you want in your select, rather than using *.  Then you have a fixed number of columns, and don't need to count.

Comment: I am not executing at any programming environment, I have some queries that I need to port to Analysis services as datasource tables, and I am having some issues, and it would be nice to know how many columns are returned for debugging purposes

Comment: [Count number of columns in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902764/count-number-of-columns-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select top 0
into _MYLOCALTEMPTABLE
from (your query here) t

select count(*)
from Information_Schema.Columns c
where table_name = '_MYLOCALTEMPTABLE'
```

You can do something similar by creating a view.

Answer (score 8):

You didn't specify your SQL Server version but I'm assuming it's not 2012. However, future readers of this question might be on 2012+ so I'm posting this answer for them.

SQL Server 2012 provides a set of procedures to provide more meta-data about queries and parameters. In this case, the stored procedure [sp_describe_first_result_set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx) will provide a handy tabular form.

There is also a DMO function, [sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878258.aspx), to provide similar content which is what you'd want to use in your example

```
DECLARE
    -- Your query goes here
    @query nvarchar(4000) = N'SELECT * FROM mdm.tblStgBatch AS TSB';

-- Tabular results
EXECUTE sys.sp_describe_first_result_set @tsql = @query;

-- Simple column count
SELECT
    COUNT(1) AS column_count
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@query, NULL, 0);
```

The new metadata discovery options are replacing [FMTONLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) which is how one would solve this problem prior to 2012. My TSQL chops are apparently not strong enough to do anything useful with it and instead I'd have to bail out to a .NET language to work with the output of FMTONLY.

```
SET FMTONLY ON;
SELECT  *
FROM    A1, A2;
SET FMTONLY OFF;
```

Comment: This was a life-saver in my case as I cannot use SELECT INTO with my query to analyze a table.   Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
--Insert into a temp table (this could be any query)
SELECT * 
INTO #temp
FROM [yourTable]

--Select from temp table
SELECT * FROM #temp

--List of columns
SELECT COUNT(name) NumOfColumns FROM tempdb.sys.columns WHERE object_id =
object_id('tempdb..#temp');

--drop temp table
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Answer (score 1):

Ugly I know:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) +
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_name = 'A1'
)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'A2'
```

Comment: The question is specifically about a query and not a table, so this does not answer the question.

Comment: There are several different queries that I want to learn how many columns they return, not only this specific example query.

Answer (score 0):

In C# do this:

SqlDataReader myReader = command.ExecuteReader();

int numFields = myReader.FieldCount;