# Number of Columns Each procedures returns T-Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I was given a task to find out how many columns each procedures **returns** (**selects**) in **sys.procedures** ?
Procedures looks like

```
    Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[stpSSC_DMND001]
    @Event           nvarchar(3),    
    @FunctionalArea  nvarchar(10),
    @Venue           nvarchar(10)       
As

BEGIN  
    BEGIN TRY 

        If @Event is null or @Event=''
            RAISERROR('@Event can not be null or empty string',16,1);
        Else if not exists(select * from ENVIRONMENT where CODE=@Event)
            RAISERROR('Value "%s" for @Event not found in ENVIRONMENT',16,1, @Event);

        IF @FunctionalArea='All'
           Set @FunctionalArea=Null        

        IF @Venue='All'
           Set @Venue=Null
                SELECT DISTINCT ENV.NAME AS [Event],
                      ORG.CODE AS [FA code], 
                      ORG.NAMEAS [FA description],
                      LOC.CODE AS [Venue code]
                FROM 
                    POSITION AS POS
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                    ENVIRONMENT AS ENV ON ENV.CODE = POS.EVENT
                WHERE ENV.CCODE_ENV=@Event
                      AND (@FunctionalArea IS NULL OR org.IDENTIFIER=@FunctionalArea)
                      AND (@Venue IS NULL OR loc.IDENTIFIER=@Venue)
                ORDER BY [FA code],
                         [Venue code]  
    END TRY

    /* ERROR HANDLING */
    BEGIN CATCH
        Declare @ErrMsg   nvarchar(200) = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        RETURN @ErrNum;
   END CATCH
END
```

I couldn't find anything familiar on google. Any suggestions?

Comment: you want `out` parameters return from procedures ? or you have a simple select query and you are returning whole `row`

Comment: take a look to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878236.aspx

Comment: no there is no out parameters. It is just simple select queries. I updated question. I need number of columns. in this case:  tpRGM_SelectSport 2

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766564/finding-number-of-columns-returned-by-a-query

Comment: Thanks, but mostly procedures ask input parameters, and they bring a lot of datas. in my case executing procedure isn't good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This works most of the time, using static analysis of a stored procedure, but there are some stored procedures that this doesn't work for:

```
SELECT
    procedures.name AS ProcedureName
    ,COUNT(*) AS FirstResultSetColumnCount
FROM 
    sys.procedures 
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT 1 as counter
    FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object( procedures.object_id,1)
    WHERE error_state IS NULL
) metadata
GROUP BY procedures.name
```

EDIT: Take a look at the following MSDN article for possible reasons why the function, sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object, would return an error_code:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878236.aspx

EDIT: This will help you on your way, but it's not exactly what you are looking for. If you wanted to use C#, I believe you could use the SqlDataReader class(Namespace: System.Data.SqlClient / Assembly: System.Data) for an automated solution.

```
DECLARE @ParameterInfo TABLE
(
    ProcedureId INT
    ,ProcedureName SYSNAME
    ,ParameterName SYSNAME
    ,TypeName SYSNAME
    ,UNIQUE(ProcedureName,ParameterName)
)

INSERT INTO @ParameterInfo 
SELECT 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY procedures.object_id) AS procedureId
    ,procedures.name
    ,parameters.name
    ,types.name
FROM sys.procedures
JOIN sys.parameters
    ON procedures.object_id = parameters.object_id
JOIN sys.types
    ON parameters.user_type_id = types.user_type_id
where 
    has_default_value = 0
AND CAST(
 case 
 when procedures.is_ms_shipped = 1 then 1
 when (
    select 
        major_id 
    from 
        sys.extended_properties 
    where 
        major_id = procedures.object_id and 
        minor_id = 0 and 
        class = 1 and 
        name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support') 
    is not null then 1
 else 0
 end AS BIT) = 0

DECLARE @Counter INT = 1;
DECLARE @ProcedureCount INT = (SELECT MAX(ProcedureId) FROM @ParameterInfo);
DECLARE @ProcedureName  SYSNAME;
DECLARE @ParameterText  VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

WHILE @Counter <= @ProcedureCount
BEGIN

    SELECT
        @ProcedureName  = ProcedureName
        ,@ParameterText = 
            @ParameterText + ', ' 
            + ParameterName + ' = '
            + CASE
                TypeName
                WHEN 'INT' THEN '0'
                WHEN 'DATE' THEN '''1/1/1900'''
                WHEN 'DATETIME' THEN '''1/1/1900'''
                --More type defaults here...
                ELSE '0'
              END

    FROM
        @ParameterInfo
    WHERE 
        ProcedureID = @Counter 

    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) =  'SET FMTONLY ON; EXEC ' + @ProcedureName + SUBSTRING(@ParameterText,2,8000) + '; SET FMTONLY OFF;'

    PRINT @SQL;
    PRINT '---';

    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;
END
```

EDIT: Or you could install SQLServer 2012 express or developer edition on your local box.

Comment: it is nice they have it in 2012 . But unluckily I use 2008 R2. it is my mistake that I didn't define it in my question.

Comment: No problem. Then in that case, the best way would be to "execute" each stored procedure while FMTONLY is on. I will post an edit with an example that would capture all column numbers.