# I have 100 Column table in SQL ,but I want to frequency for each column at a time,Is it possible in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

```
EMPNO   ENAME   JOB      MGR    ------------------
7369    SMITH   CLERK    7902   
7499    ALLEN   SALESMAN 7698   
7499    SMITH   SALESMAN 7698   
7369    JONES   MANAGER  7839
```

I need Out put like this

```
Empno cnt ENAME  cnt ------------ Same out put remaining columns also
7369  2   SMITH  2
7499  2   ALLEN  1
      JONES  1
```

Comment: Why do you need the count of the `Empno` and `ENAME` separately? Wouldn't they be the same?

Comment: This may help you-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464991/to-get-total-number-of-columns-in-a-table-in-sql

Comment: Why do you have different employees (SMITH and JONES) with the same employee number (7369)? Shouldn't an employee number uniquely identify an employee?

Comment: Somethings wrong in the design.

Comment: You are asking if you can get the counts of occurrence of the column entry, the answer is yes. producing it the way you like is impossible.

Comment: I need Frequency for each individual column in dynamic code

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic909174-338-1.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you mean by `I want to frequency`.

Answer (score 1):

may be you should look into this Solution as it gives exact answer for posted  output but we need to work around for Dynamic Solution

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    (MPNO int, ENAME varchar(5), JOB varchar(8), MGR int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (MPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR)
VALUES
    (7369, 'SMITH', 'CLERK', 7902),
    (7499, 'ALLEN', 'SALESMAN', 7698),
    (7499, 'SMITH', 'SALESMAN', 7698),
    (7369, 'JONES', 'MANAGER', 7839)
;


select T.MPNO, T.cnt, TT.ENAME,TT.cnt,TTT.JOB,TTT.cnt,TTTT.MGR,TTTT.cnt
from (select g.MPNO,count(MPNO)cnt, row_number() over (order by MPNO) as seqnum
      from @Table1 g
      GROUP BY g.MPNO
     ) T full outer join
     (select g.ENAME, count(ENAME)cnt,row_number() over (order by ENAME) as seqnum
      from @Table1 g
      GROUP BY g.ENAME
     ) TT
     on T.seqnum = TT.seqnum
     full outer join 
     (select g.JOB, count(JOB)cnt,row_number() over (order by JOB) as seqnum
      from @Table1 g
      GROUP BY g.JOB)TTT
      on TT.seqnum = TTT.seqnum
       full outer join 
     (select g.MGR, count(MGR)cnt,row_number() over (order by MGR) as seqnum
      from @Table1 g
      GROUP BY g.MGR)TTTT
      on TTTT.seqnum = TTT.seqnum
     ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.EMPNO, A.CNT, B.ENAME,B.CNT,C.JOB,C.CNT,D.MGR,D.CNT
FROM (SELECT G.EMPNO,COUNT(EMPNO)CNT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EMPNO) AS NUMBER
      FROM #TABLE G
      GROUP BY G.EMPNO
     ) A FULL OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT G.ENAME, COUNT(ENAME)CNT,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ENAME) AS NUMBER
      FROM #TABLE G
      GROUP BY G.ENAME
     ) B
     ON A.NUMBER = B.NUMBER
    LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT G.JOB, COUNT(JOB)CNT,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY JOB) AS NUMBER
      FROM #TABLE G
      GROUP BY G.JOB)C
      ON B.NUMBER = C.NUMBER
      LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT G.MGR, COUNT(MGR)CNT,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MGR) AS NUMBER
      FROM #TABLE G
      GROUP BY G.MGR)D
      ON D.NUMBER = C.NUMBER
```